# Tool needed for remote software deployment to Windows PC's over internet

Tags: windows, deployment

Can anyone recommend a commercial software package that enables automated rollouts of a bespoke software package across the internet?
We are looking at approximately 1000 remote PC's that our organisation owns, geographically scattered and with varying bandwidths available from a central site. The PC's are not manned, they are used as server machines.
The tool needs to have some scripting facilities too.
The tool needs to be able to push software to the remote site in an automated way.
We also need it to be able to reboot the remote machine too.

Any ideas anyone?

thanks.

Comment: You'll need to tell us what OS's you're talking about here.

Answer (score 1):

There is Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager, it lets you install MSI packages (or run any script you wrote) automatically on a large number of computers.
You can setup datastores on sites where bandwidth to your main datacenter is low and also force reboots.